# jQuery onclick div checks a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="member">
    <input type="checkbox" value="64" style="display:none;" name="memberId[]" />
    <div class="memberInfo">John Doe</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get a jQuery script that when a visitor presses the `member` div it will change the background color, and check the `memberId` checkbox.

How should such a jQuery script look like?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably do this with [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) which allows you to set two handlers: one for the first time a handler is triggered and then one for the next time, repeating as necessary.

```
$('.member').toggle(function() { // first time
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000')
           .find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
}, function() { // second time
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff')
           .find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Although this should work as I see it works on jsfiddle, it doesn't work on my page for some reason. my member div is inside a jquery dialog, does that make any difference?

Comment: @Or W It shouldn't matter. Could you post your actual code somewhere accessible?

Comment: Fixed it by wrapping your function with jQuery(document).ready(function (){

Comment: @Or W Excellent -- I was taking that as read! Sorry for not being more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        $(".member").click(function() {
            $("input[name=memberId]").attr('checked', true);
            $(this).css('background-color','#F00');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Edit: The others were way faster than me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.member').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#ABC098');
    $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',true)
});
```

Comment: Although this should work as I see it works on jsfiddle, it doesn't work on my page for some reason. my member div is inside a jquery dialog, does that make any difference?