# jQuery td onclick to set a checkbox, no bubbling

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to click on the td element in a table and have it check or uncheck a checkbox in a sibling td on the same row.

- Clicking the checkbox should still
  work normally.
- Clicking the td
  element the checkbox resides in
  should also check the checkbox.
- Clicking different td's should not
  require double clicks (reset click)
  due to a bad toggle implementation

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cJ2us/

Please note, yes this is very similar to a number of questions, please don't link any duplicates unless you actually understand the problem I have and how the answers given there do not fit my question. e.g.

[Jquery event on wrapped input radio override 'checked' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096410/jquery-event-on-wrapped-input-radio-override-checked-event)
Not checkboxes

[jQuery onclick div checks a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868769/jquery-onclick-div-checks-a-checkbox)
toggle doesn't allow clicking on seperate td's to carry out each check and uncheck

[Find the Checkbox in Sibling <td> and check it using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307993/find-the-checkbox-in-sibling-td-and-check-it-using-jquery) doesn't fit this example, code doesn't actually work how answerer thinks

In saying that, if you find a dupe that fits let me know! I just want a workable solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U3636/ is my solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works, is it what you want?

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    var chk = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:checkbox").get(0);
    if(e.target != chk)
    {
        chk.checked = !chk.checked;
    }
});
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xSzpZ/)

Comment: OK, it should work now, e.srcElement should be changed to e.target.

Answer (score 1):

Use labels.

```
<label for='cheboxID'>LABEL</label>
```

---

Here is a js solution: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eWh5F/

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    var checkbox = $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).get(0);
    var checked = checkbox.checked;
    if (checked == false) checkbox.checked = true;
    else checkbox.checked = false;
});
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't allow for filler space very well. Could maybe block them and make them fill the whole td but I'd rather a jquery solution sorry.

Comment: @NotHelpful -- i posted a jQuery solution

Comment: FF issues with the checkbox - everyone seems to get stuck there :}

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").click(function(e) {

    var $checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox']");
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));



});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJ2us/12/

Comment: clicking on checkbox does not check it!

Answer (score 0):

there is another way ,full javascript

```js
 function aply(t){
   let chk = t.firstChild;
    chk.checked =!chk.checked;
 }
 function stopProp(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 }
```

```css
.table tr td{
height:50px;
width:100px;
background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td  onclick="aply(this)"><input type="checkbox" onclick="stopProp(event);"  />1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  onclick="aply(this)"><input type="checkbox" onclick="stopProp(event);"  />2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```