# Using JQuery to change CSS of td on td click or checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my `td` to change color if the user clicks the `td` itself or the checkbox.

Right now if the user clicks the `td` the css **will** change and the checkbox will check/uncheck.

**But if the checkbox is clicked**, *nothing changes*. additionally if the page is refreshed the checkboxes are checked, but the CSS is gone.

What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzjtekky)

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="1">A</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="2">B</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="3">C</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="4">D</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
var chosen = {'background-color': '#9F1313', 'color': '#fff'};
var unchosen = {'background-color': 'transparent', 'color': '#000'};

$('td').click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('input')) {
        $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', function (i, value) {
            highlight(this, $(this).closest('td'));
            return !value;
        });
    }
});

function highlight(cb, cell) {
    if (cb.checked) {
        $(cell).css(unchosen);
    } else {
        $(cell).css(chosen);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery td onclick to set a checkbox, no bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513129/jquery-td-onclick-to-set-a-checkbox-no-bubbling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the event bubbling from the checkbox to the parent `td`, however you can both avoid the problem completely, make the code more semantic, have better support, and simpler by using a `label` and then just toggling a CSS class on the parent `td` based on the `checked` state of the checkbox. Try this:

```js
$('.table-responsive :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('chosen', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  td {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
  }
  
  td.chosen {
    background-color: #9F1313;
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="1"> A</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="2"> B</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="3"> C</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="my-group[]" value="4"> D</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion this will bind event in both TD and checkbox while also prevent from double triggering.

```
$('td').on('click',function(event){ 
     var td  = $(this);
     var checkBox = $(this).find('input:checkbox');

     if($(event.target).is('input')){                 // checks if event target is checkbox
        event.stopPropagation();                      // prevents triggering click event on TD too
     } else {
        checkBox.trigger('click');                    // if its TD, triggers checkbox click event
        return;                                       // and stop the code
     }

     if(checkBox.is(':checked')){                     // checks if checkbox is checked!
        td.css('background-color','red');
     } else {
        td.css('background-color','transparent');
     }

 });
```

You can see it in action here :
https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/PjVXrm

Hope it helps at least.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from the event bubbling add `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` to your click event.

```
$('td').click(function(event) {
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
if (!$(event.target).is('input')) {
$('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', function(i, value) {
  highlight(this, $(this).closest('td'));
  return !value;
});
}
});
```